# Helm hook not deleting previous release resource on upgrade

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-helm

I have the below annotation for my secrets

```
annotations:
     "helm.sh/hook": "pre-install,pre-upgrade"
     "helm.sh/hook-weight": "1"
     "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": "before-hook-creation"
```

it's giving me the following error when I try to upgrade.

> Error: UPGRADE FAILED: secrets "my-secret" already exists

My expectation is it should delete previous release hook and create a new one

Helm Version:

- Client: 2.7.2
- Server: 2.7.2

Comment: Are you creating secret `my-secret` using your helm chart?

Comment: It was already created when I did a `helm install`

Comment: Can you share link of the chart that you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after digging docs, came to know that `"helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": "before-hook-creation"` is not available in Helm version `2.7.2` it is available in `2.9.0`

Comment: Could be same is happening to me?  I am using Helm version `v.2.13.1`